# Why won't this print the if?

Tags: java, if-statement

I'm trying to make a text based game but my If statement won't print. Whats wrong?

```
   System.out.print("What path do you choose?: ");
   String pathChoice= kb.nextLine();
   System.out.println(" ");
   System.out.println(" ");
   System.out.println(" ");
   if (pathChoice==("North") || pathChoice==("north")){
       System.out.println("You begin walking north and encounter an ogre of significant size.");
       System.out.println("You draw your crude sword. How will you attack? ");
```

Comment: You are using == instead of .equals for string comparisons

Comment: To compare `String`s use `.equals()` not `==`.

Comment: can make input string to lower case (after check not null or maybe kb always returns not null) and then use equals